# What does the writer mean in the highlighted sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a paragraph as follows:

> One cannot escape socialization, because it is an inevitable process and phenomenon that will always exist; it is impossible and even detrimental to avoid. In general, socialization is a good thing, but it can inhibit you in some cases. Being aware of these nonconscious beliefs and how they affect your behavior is vital because, without awareness, you will not understand why you think or act as you do. 
>   **It is because of socialization that people make sure they look carefully before crossing a street and they face a certain direction in an elevator.** We are all raised to follow certain procedures, most of which are helpful. But socialization also causes people to adopt behavior that interferes with the natural development process.

What does the writer mean in the highlighted sentence? Can you explain it to me Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The writer explains this sentence in his next sentence, he is trying to tell that we do things because other people do it to. We sometimes follow everyone else without questioning if that is the right thing to do, we do not stand in an elevator facing the corner, we face the door because that is what everyone does.

However in both occasions (looking before crossing a street, and facing the door in an elevator) it is also something to keep our selves safe, we look before crossing because we don't want to be hit by a car. And we look at the door because we want to know if the people that step into the elevator with us are friendly, if they look trustworthy and aren't going to kill you. Looking at the exit also helps in case of an emergency so you immediately know what way to go in order to get to safety.

In his next sentence: "We are all raised to follow certain procedures, most of which are helpful." he does state that even though we do this because everyone else does it, it can be helpful, like the examples he gave which I've explained.